# Problem uploading multiple files with the same name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, file-upload, html5-video

I need to be able to upload different files with the same name to different input within one page.
My problem is that the browser caches the first file and then the subsequent ones are not getting uploaded.

I use `antd` `Upload` component

```
<Upload
      onChange={() => false}
      beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
      accept="video/mp4,video/quicktime"
      multiple={false}
      className="video-input"
    >
      <UploadLocalVideoIcon />
    </Upload>
```

Is there any way to prevent the browser from caching files by their on certain pages.
Due to backend requirements, I'm not allowed to append anything to file names on upload. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. Can you add more detail about how you render your multiple Upload Component?

Comment: Basically, it's just a page where you have multiple file inputs. Each file input only accepts one file. There is a lot of other stuff there, so it's going to be difficult to extract the code that is relevant for the issue

Comment: Because I tried to create multiple Upload Components in here: https://usw27.csb.app/ and it definitely can. I remove your `beforeUpload` function, as you don't put your logic here.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that after upload I get a URL that I then use in React Player. So basically, each upload has it's own player, kinda like a preview. So If I upload filename.mov in one input and then a different file with the same name into the other input I will see 2 player components having the same video which is the one uploaded the first. I hope it makes sense :)

Comment: So the process should be like this: Upload -> Get URL from BE? -> React Player (this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player ?). You should check if: 1. You get the correct URL from BE, 2. Check if you send a different video to the BE, 3. Check each player has a different URL.